# JHipster Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: spring, jhipster

I extended my JHipster application and wrote a service class with the following code:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class AmazonClient {

private AmazonS3 s3Client;

@Value("${amazonProperties.endpointUrl}")
private String endpointUrl;

@Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
private String bucketName;

@Value("${amazonProperties.accessKey}")
private String accessKey;

@Value("${amazonProperties.secretKey}")
private String secretKey;

public AmazonClient() {

}

@PostConstruct
private void initializeAmazon() {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
    this.s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
}
```

my application-dev.yml includes the following:

```
amazonProperties:
  endpointUrl: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
  accessKey: XYZ
  secretKey: XYZ
  bucketName: XYZ
```

When I start my application with mvwn everything works. When I run my tests I get the following Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'amazonProperties.endpointUrl' in value "${amazonProperties.endpointUrl}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using jhipster, this happens because you put the credentials in application-dev.yml, and this file will be visible only in dev profile

You need to put in the `application.yml` file under the `src/main/test/resources` folder. The test runner will look for properties in this file.

Comment: Correct but don't write your secrets in application-*.yml because they are archived in your source code repository rather use an external location like environment variables and in application-*.yml refer to the env vars.